# How to wrap a TF Estimator in a Keras Layer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tensorflow-estimator

I have some code already written, using TensorFlow `Estimator`.

Since I would like to work with Keras (and I need to use the `Estimator` code), is there any way to wrap the `Estimator` into a Keras `Layer` ?

Comment: It is very easy. Just use `tf.keras` and you can operate on the same graph with one API

Comment: I'm not sure how to understand your comment.. How should I use tf.keras after an estimator ?

For example, can I use a Keras layer inside a model_fn of an Estimator ?

Comment: Yes can use it inside. But you have to use tf.keras not the standalone version. But also outside. You access the graph and use the tensors as input for your keras functions. Maybe specifiy your problem in more detail with code?